# celery redis key unacked issue

Tags: django, redis, celery

I am using the Glitchtip service, which employs Celery to initiate worker processes for job processing. This setup involves a combination of Celery and Redis, where Redis serves as a message broker.

Upon sending a substantial number of requests, I've noticed a spike in the Redis key named "unacked," which eventually causes Redis to run out of memory.

In my environment configuration, I have set the following parameters:

**CELERY_ACKS_ON_FAILURE_OR_TIMEOUT** is set to False.

**CELERY_ACKS_LATE** is set to True.

I'm wondering if there are any additional environment parameters that I should consider setting in order to better control the processing rate. Your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Ref ->

1. https://gitlab.com/glitchtip